# In a Delta query, CreatedBy is sometimes null and sometimes not null but missing User property

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, microsoft-graph, azure-ad, graph-api

I am tracking changes to files and folders using delta query with Graph API version 5.12 (not beta).

In order to reflect the changes in our system we rely on the `CreatedBy` property. The problem is that this property is unreliable from SharePoint.

Sometimes it is present with the user that made the change, sometimes it is present but the User property is null, and sometimes it is simply null.

I do not fully understand what is going on. I believe it has something to do with the fact that the syncing is done using an Azure Active directory app with Application type permissions because sometimes the property `CreatedBy.Application.DisplayName` has the name of that app.

Can someone shed a light on how this works? What situation causes a file or a folder returned by a delta query to have no `CreatedBy` information?